# hmisc hist in R with density

Tags: r, hmisc

I'm trying to plot a histogram for a dataframe in R. I'm using the Hmisc package to do the same. It generates a very nice plot for categorical data except for one problem. It displays the frequencies instead of probabilities. Please find a code sample (from the package documentation, although my data is categorical but that doesn't matter) below:

```
x <- rnorm(200,0,2)+1; y <- x^2
x2 <- round((x+rnorm(200))/2)*2
x3 <- round((x+rnorm(200))/4)*4
dfram <- data.frame(y,x,x2,x3)
hist(dfram)
```

How do I modify the plot above to display normalised frequencies?

I have already tried `hist(dfram, type='density')` but `type ='density'` is  an argument to histSpike function to plot kernel densities. I have also tried `hist(dfram,f=F)` and `hist(dfram,prob=T)` (which are essentially the same from what I understand) but the histograms still show frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Take the output of `hist`, which contains the normalized frequencies in `$density`, and plot (e.g. `barplot` ) those results.
That is,

```
foo<-hist(dfram)  #although you probably wanted hist(dfram$y) or some such)
barplot(foo$density)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using the `hist.data.frame` function from the Hmisc package. I tried your suggest but it didn't work for me. Your suggestion applies for the hist function from the base package. Attaching another example to make the problem even more clear.
`a<-data.frame(sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=T),sample(LETTERS[1:2],1000,replace=T))`
`hist(a)`

Comment: @AjinkyaGhorpade Take a look at the help file for `Hmisc::hist` and see what values are returned.  Most likely either the densities or at least the bin quantities are available. If the latter, just normalize the bin quantities against themselves.

Comment: I did check the return values. The function just returns number of pages drawn.

Comment: Then my recommendation would be to use `graphics::hist` for each dataset and then build the multi-graph with `ggplot` or `grid`